# visit a garden in the north, and you could be

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjunctions, coordination

I was told that a bare infinitive phrase followed by "and" and a sentence could mean "if ... then ...." 
For example, "Give John 10 dollars, and he will ask for 100 dollars" means "If you give John 10 dollars, he will ask for 100 dollars."

What about the following example? Does it sound perfectly natural?

> The country is famous for its rapid public transportation network. Visit a garden in the north in the morning, and you could be climbing a mountain in the south in the afternoon.

Comment: The sentence and grammar applied is correct. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

For the "John" example, This is the case. Both sentences have the same meaning. Another example of this is

> Give a mouse a cookie, and it will want more

is the same as

> If you give a mouse a cookie, then it will want more

however, the "garden" statement isn't causal(it doesnt suggest that one event will cause the other). that is the only difference. It reads correctly

Comment: But there is no causal relation holding in the garden example; one could climb a mountain in the south without visiting a garden in the north.

Comment: One could also not give money to john, or a cookie to a mouse. one could spend that money for john on cookies to eat for oneself

Comment: I am talking about the logical formula p --> q implicit in the construction "Imperative, and S +V."

Comment: Is the example in the OP saying visiting a northern garden could cause a person to climb a southern mountain?

Comment: The examples you offered all describe a causal relation.

Comment: Oh. the question has been edited since ive answered it. this answer no longer applies